# Problem on Do Carmo's definition of manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In the book *Riemannian Geometry*, Do Carmo gave his definition of manifold without metionning to the topology on the set M. However, the usual way to define manifold is always to supposing M is a topological space with some restrictions on the topology, such as $A_{2}$ or $T_{2}$.
[image]

Later, he made a remark on this. As he said, we can induce a natural topology on M using the differential structure.
[image]

**My question is that:**

What happened if the topology induced in this way may not be $T_{2}$ or $A_{2}$? Do Carmo metioned this problem but he didn't give an answer. I am in a mess now...Help, thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: After introducing these axioms, does he make use of them later? They are both necessary, for example the line with doubled origin is permitted by his definition of differentiable manifold, but is not Hausdorff.

Comment: @Joppy He then introduced the partition of unity, which needs the condition of A_2.  However, he didn’t say how to put this condition to the so called natural topology.

Comment: I think the point is that in addition to his definition, you need to assume both these axioms in order to do differential geometry (such as using partitions of unity). These axioms do *not* follow from the definition.

Comment: @Joppy Yeah, I try to understand what he said with more modern definition. But that was quite a mess...Is there anyone reading the book before find this problem.? How does them get rid of it?